# Redux state is updated only after logout

Tags: node.js, express, redux

I'm trying to learn redux by building a small project and I got stuck.
I want to update the user avatar path in mongodb which works fine btw. The problem is that the redux avatar state is not being updated only if I logout and log back in. I feel a bit confused by redux and I feel like I'm missing something here.
Code bellow:

AuthReducer:

```
const initialState = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  user: {}
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_CURRENT_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: !isEmpty(action.payload),
        user: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

AuthActions:

```
//Set logged in user

export const setCurrentUser = decoded => {
  return {
    type: SET_CURRENT_USER,
    payload: decoded
  };
};

//Update avatar
export const updateAvatar = userAvatar => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post("/api/users/avatar", userAvatar)
    .then(res => dispatch(setCurrentUser(res.data)))
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.data.response
      })
    );
};
```

Update function:

```
// @route   POST api/users/avatar
// @desc    Upload user avatar
// @access  Private
router.post(
  "/avatar",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    const errors = {};
    upload(req, res, err => {
      if (err) {
        errors.uploadErr = err;
        res.status(500).json(errors);
      } else {
        const avatarPath = req.file.path.replace(/\\/g, "/");

        const finalPath = "../" + avatarPath.slice(14);
        User.findOneAndUpdate(
          { _id: req.user.id },
          { $set: { avatar: finalPath } },
          { new: true }
        )
          .then(user => res.json(user))
          .catch(err => res.status(404).json(err));
      }
    });
  }
);
```

As you can see I just store the avatar image path in the db and return the user object. As I mentioned, saving to mongo works fine. After that, having the user obj I dispatch SET_CURRENT_USER.
The state is being changed only after I log out and then log back in.. Should I set something different?

EDIT: It works if I log the user out and then log him back in by calling a redux action.. I don't think this is best practice but I can't figure how to do this properly.

Comment: When and where do you call the updateAvatar action ?

Comment: I call the action in a component with a click event. That works fine, the action is being called.